# What is difference between router.Static() and router.Use(static.Serve()) on the gin?

Tags: go, go-gin

I was just reading the documentation of gin and found there are 2 different way to set assets folder to the server, one is using `Static()` method of the router as follow:

```golang
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func main() {
        r := gin.Default()
        r.Static("/assets", "./assets")
```

Then the other is using static middleware as follows:

```golang
package main

import (
       "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
       "github.com/gin-contrib/static"
)

func main() {
        r := gin.Default()
        r.Use(static.Serve("/", static.LocalFile("./assets", false)))
```

Is there any difference between these 2 ways about speed, side-effect, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option [from](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/982daeb1ecdced87bbef6c11783a640eb88a193a/routergroup.go#L160-L168):

> Static serves files from the given file system root.
>   Internally a http.FileServer is used, therefore http.NotFound is used instead
>   of the Router's NotFound handler.

Second option [link](https://github.com/gin-contrib/static/blob/master/static.go#L58-L70):

> Static returns a middleware handler that serves static files in the given directory.

both uses `http.FileServer` under the hood.